# Tableview cell reusability, cutting label texts

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

[Here I attached the gif file. Refer this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NV9so.jpg)

In my tableview I have a custom xib cell with autolayout. When I run the project, getting the problem like the gif file.

Its my tableview function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "requestsCell", for: indexPath) as? RequestsTableViewCell
    cell?.backgroundColor = .clear

    let passengerName = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    let bookingCreator = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    let department = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
    let product = cell?.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel
    passengerName.text = "Muhammed yasheed"
    bookingCreator.text = "Muhammed Yasheed"
    department.text = "Programming"
    product.text = "Flight"


    cell?.approvedView.isHidden = false
    cell?.cancelView.isHidden = true



    return cell!

}
```

Comment: Not related but `viewWithTag` in a table view cell is outdated. Use a custom class file and outlets. And force-unwrap the type cast to `RequestsTableViewCell` to avoid all the redundant question marks since you are force-unwrapping the cell anyway at the end.

Comment: I know. I'm using a custom class file and outlets. Here I just checked if any issue with the custom class.

Comment: Looks like xib/auto layout problem. Check your storyboard and how you laid out your cells. You can set text wrapping to true or false for your UILabels.

Comment: @dirkgroten only two or three cells are like this. All other cells are working fine. When I scroll down and again scroll up the cell's labels becomes to the correct position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. Just add cell?.layoutIfNeeded() in cellForRowAt indexpath

```
cell?.layoutIfNeeded()
```